# HOCON included java properties file contains special characters

Tags: java, scala, properties, akka, hocon

I need to include java properties file to my application.conf file.
This properties file contains special (to hocon) characters like '*' or ':' in properties values. So I get a run-time error when application starts and tries to load configuration.

Is there a way to include properties file in hocon file with escaping this special characters? I cannot modify this property file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `double-quotes`.

eg:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
```

Comment: I cannot modify included properties file.

Comment: I have * characters in properties containing cron expressions, they cannot be escaped this way.